# How to get the distribution of GPA of the class

Tags: python, list, range

Let say a list ***a*** contains the GP (grade points) for some particular subject. The length of the list is the number of students. How can I calculate the distribution of GP over 0-4 scale? The GP ranges from 0 to 4. Therefore, I want the distribution of **x** over **0 to 4**.

Comment: What is meant by "distribution"? Are you using that term as a technical term from statistics?

Comment: Yes, like on x-axies I will have scale from 0 to 4, and y axies shows the frequency. I am new to python therefore I have no idea where to start. I am matlab user.

Comment: It looks like the answer from @Alex might be what you want. If that's true, consider accepting his answer and maybe adjust your post so it says "draw a graph of the distribution of" instead of "calculate the distribution of", so it's more clear that you want a visualization of the distribution.

Answer (score 3):

Check out numpy's histogram: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html

```
hist = np.histogram(a, bins=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

If are using matplotlib, you can use the following to plot it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(a, bins=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a program that creates a list of ordered pairs which has each entry of an original list, together with a count. There are many ways to do this, here is the way I would do it:

```
from collections import Counter
original_list_example = [2.6, 3.1, 2.6, 3.0]
distribution = Counter(original_list_example)
```

You basically will have your original list, which you called `GP`. When you put this into `Counter` you will get ordered pairs, for each entry in `GP`, how often it appears. You should store the result of `Counter(GP)` in a new variable, which I call `distribution`, so you can use it later. You can display this for example by adding `print(distribution)`.

It's not entirely clear from your question exactly what you're trying to do and how, but as far as I can tell, this should solve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
a = [1.9, 1.8, 0.8, 3.7]
a.sort()

print(a)
```

`sort()` sorts the list in ascending order. Running this will produce `[0.8, 1.8, 1.9, 3.7]`, an ordered list.

Obviously you would replace the arbitrarily chosen numbers with the GP values that you have.